# Cancel package installation based on contents of package

Tags: packages

I need to block certain packages from being installed based on the items in the package. If a Sitecore item in the package matches a certain condition then the package should not be installed. I have tried using the `packageinstall:items:starting` event as this has a reference to all the items in the package.

I tried setting `SitecoreEventArgs.Result.Cancel` to true or throwing an exception in this event. However in either case the items in the package are still getting installed. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions? You can use that to build dialogs and even inspect packages. Perhaps using SPE scripts you can determine whether a package is eligible for installation.

Comment: You're turning a user problem into a software problem